# How do I install and consume a COM object in Windows Azure?

Tags: windows, deployment, com, azure, cloud

I have a lot of 32-bit C++ code that I want to run in Windows Azure Compute Service. The code is already packaged into a COM server and so I'd like to consume that server from managed code that will service external requests.

I googled but can't find any details on how to deploy a COM server under Windows Azure. How do I do that? Is there a guide? What limitations are there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you could deploy the COM objects as binaries and then register them using a startup script - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433178 - "Exercise 2: Using Start-Up Tasks to Register a COM Component"

Comment: Nice Ryan :) Stuart, be sure to pull down the Platform Training Kit. It is by far the best that MS has put out to date

Comment: @dunnry I suspect you might have a biased opinion on that particular part of the training kit...

Comment: The page linked to above is no longer available on MSDN. However, this URL appears to be a copy of the original content: http://www.wou.edu/~rvitolo06/WATK/Labs/AdvancedWebAndWorkerRoles/Lab.html/html/DocSet_8e10f13b-54fa-43ea-9d3c-1fb439e95d7e.html

Comment: Actually, the original MSDN article can be viewed via the Wayback Machine: http://web.archive.org/web/20110727021351/http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg433178